# how to include wordpress blog feature into codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I Have a Scenario wherein i have developed the whole site using codeigniter 
and  need an extra blogging feature .

So i was wondering whether it is possible to integrate only the blog feature of wordpress in codeigniter Any pointers/suggestions would be helpful to start with.

Comment: Include how?  You could iframe the blog in a view and it would be included

Comment: like the capability of including wordpress functionality in codeigniter view something like that

Comment: In that case (and this might end up being complicated) you might want to look at the [Wordpress API](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/) and see what you can do from there

Comment: Extend `system/core/Exceptions.php` to `application/core/MY_Exceptions.php`. Overload the `show_404` method and have it include the `index.php` file from the wordpress directory.  You may need to `chdir()`.

Answer (score 1):

I Actually Figured it out , I installed wordpress inside codeigniter

And then loaded the **wp-load.php** file in the **index.php** file of **codeigniter** which loads all the constants and other defaults

which gave me access to **wordpress functions** in codeigniter that is call **wp_function** name to access it inside codeigniter view file.

But suggestion from the fellow developers was to have a **separate wordpress site** and linking to the site from the **Main Site** .

I did follow it if some one wants to try out accessing wordpress functions in codeigniter then they can follow the above process

Comment: If so Can I use wordpress as back end and my own model and controller methods as front end to fetch data from wordpress database? If yes, How can I do that?